# Does "Though she felt ill, she still went to work" sound natural?

Tags: sentence-construction

> **Though** she felt ill, she **still** went to work.

Does this sentence sound natural to you?

Comment: It sounds fine.  Naturalness judgments, though, need to be made in context.

Comment: As per Stack Exchange policy, [please do not include "thanks"](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/2950/148099) in your questions. Rather, express your thanks by voting, since that is the most public form of thanks possible, and it is what makes the the site possible. You've asked 77 questions, nearly all of which have been answered, but only cast 13 votes. Please help upvote all interesting questions and helpful answers that you encounter.

Answer (score 1):

There are a few places where ***Although*** and ***Though*** can be used interchangeably, but as a general rule of thumb-

1. Although is used at the beginning of a sentence (where a comma is followed by the clause).
2. Though is **mostly** used in the middle or end of a sentence, and sometimes in the beginning when followed by an adjective (*Though green, the banana was edible.*)

You would be better off using "although" in your sentence:

> **Although** she felt ill, she **still** went to work.

Note, however, that *although* is slightly more formal than *though*.

Comment: You could also say _"Even though she felt ill,"_ to be a little less formal.

Comment: 'Though' is not mostly used in the middle or at the end of a sentence. The Corpus of Contemporary English has over 16,000 citations for 'Though' as the first word in a sentence, and only 350 of these are for 'Though' followed immediately by an adjective.. 'Although' at the beginning of a sentence is far more common (43,000 citations), but it is far from the automatic or 'better' choice.